# WatchKit: How to disable and enable wrist raise programmatically in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I want to be able to disable wrist raise in a particular interface controller.

It will needs to disable and enable wrist raise within a watch app.

Does anyone know if it is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by disabling "wrist rise"? Activating a display on Watch on wrist rising?

Comment: my bad. typo. I mean disabling and enabling wrist raise in the codes. Because there are times when I need the screen of the watch to be always on at an interface controller.

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible. Other questions have been asked regarding changing settings of Apple Watch programmatically, which is what this is asking, and I haven't seen any indications that this is possible.

Comment: yeah I figured. Seems like only the user can change it for now.